# Suggestions on how to proceed with reverse engineering Installshield silent crash

Tags: windows, reverse-engineering, installshield

I found an old abandonware game CD (Metal Knight Mission: Terminate Resistance) from my childhood in some boxes the other day. Its a game from 1998 that was built for Windows 95/98 and DirectX 5.0. After trying to get the game to work in VMs for a few days, I gave up and have pivoted to trying to get it to work on Windows 10 (since that would be ideal).

The game wouldn't install on Windows 10. To work around this, I tried to copy the files from a successful install on the VM and run them directly. After some reverse engineering and applying some patches I was able to get the screen size up to 1920x1080, but only the intro videos would play before a black screen. At this point it looked like my issue was missing registry keys...which makes sense since I never installed the program.

Pivoting back to trying to install the game as intended. After copying the game disc files to C:\ and creating a SETUP.LID file, autorun.exe will bring me to the game launcher. **The problem: when I hit install game, autoconf.exe calls setup.exe. Installshield 5.0 will pop up and reach 99% before silently closing.** After Installshield closes, the game launcher freezes up and only the exit button functions. See the image below for what it looks like right before it silently crashes.

[image: Metal Knight Install Failure]

I've tried these things:

- Using different Windows compatibility modes.
- Using the /s, /f2, /debuglog commands for installshield to try to get some info on why setup.exe is crashing. No logfiles were generated.
- Running setup.exe in x32dbg. x32dbg states its 'not a valid PE file!'.
- Running autoconf.exe in x32dbg and setting a breakpoint where setup.exe is called. This didn't provide any info on why it crashes. No exceptions are thrown.
- Loading up setup.exe in Ghidra. So far I haven't found anything interesting poking around but I also don't know what I'm looking for.

Does anyone else have any ideas where to go from here? Could I somehow extract the installation info from setup.exe and create a modern installer for it? These are the files I have to work with.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried just waiting? I remember similar issue with some other old game. I waited ~5 mins and it finally reached 100%.

Comment: The progress bar closes. Letting it sit for 10 minutes doesn't do anything. In task manager I can watch the '32 bit setup launcher' startup when the progress window spawns. When it closes the setup launcher task ends and a background process named '32-bit Installshield Deleter' runs for a few seconds.

Answer (score -2):

To play Metal Knight terminate resistance on win 10 you have to download the game, to do it go to google and search "my abandonware metal knight", enter my abandonware site, download the rip version of the game, then go to this link: https://github.com/narzoul/DDrawCompat/releases  , download the DDrawCompat file and insert it on the game folder, after that, you have only to start the game clicking the mk.exe file. to enable the save with the portable version of the game you have to rename the folder into "Metal Knight" and create a folder with the name "sav".
I hope this can be useful. I hope one day to play MK in multiplayer with others die hard fans